# Find the roots of polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

I want to find roots for the following polynomial. The last term is `-50`. I tried `1, -50, -1, 50, 2, -25, -2, 25, -5, 5` values for $x$.  But none of them equals $0$. I'm not sure how to proceed.

$$3x^3 + 2x^2 + 75x -50 = 0$$

To all critics, I do put in efforts. As an example please look at questions asked this morning [calculate polynomial equation from roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273262/calculate-polynomial-equation-from-roots). I'm taking a Math correspondence. The book has very little explanation and few errors.

Please don't criticize. I'm really stuck.

Comment: If there is no mistake in the coefficients, there are no rational roots. So what techniques have you used in your studies so far? There is a cubic formula but it's very unwieldy and unlikely to be part of your course.

Comment: I've used the quadratic formula, compare the equation on both sides, long division so far

Comment: I can't say for sure the point of the question but if one of the signs on this polynomial is wrong, there are rational roots. For instance $3x^{3}+2x^{2}-75x-50$ has three rational roots, $3x^{3}-2x^{2}+75x-50$ has one, and $3x^{3}+2x^{2}+75x+50$ has one.

Comment: The rational root theorem says rational roots of a polynomial will be of the form $p/q$, where $p$ is a factor of the constant term and $q$ is a factor of the leading coefficient.  So there are other rational root candidates to check aside from the ones you listed (like $50/3$, $1/3$, etc.).  But the polynomial you gave, $3x^3 + 2x^2 + 75x - 50$, does indeed have no rational roots.

Comment: There are no rational roots (the real root is 0.64485... the two others are complex). Whereas, if you have had  $3x^3 + 2x^2 + 75x + 50$ with a plus sign for the last term, it would have been factorizable as $(3x+2)(...)$.

Comment: @law-of-fives the polynomial is exactly as I typed in question.

Comment: @tilper p/q technique you mentioned is not in course. what could be possible answer for this question?

Comment: @JeanMarie How did you get the 0.64485.. ?

Comment: The roots of the given polynomial are very unpleasant.  I suspect there is a typo in the assignment you were given if that's really what it says.

Comment: I got this root with a numerical software (Matlab). Exact solutions to third degree equations are usually not tractable...

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for your valuable time and efforts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $$f(x)=3x^3 + 2x^2 + 75x -50$$ $$f'(x)=9x^2+4x+75$$ The first derivative does not show any real root and it is then always positive. Now, by inspection, $f(0)=-50$, $f(1)=+30$; so, only one real root between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: I got following answer on https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3x%5E3%2B2x%5E2%2B75x-50. x≈0.64485 and x≈-0.6558 + 5.0414 i and x≈-0.6558 - 5.0414 i. I didn't understand calculations. The calculation is definitely out of scope for my course.

Comment: @gmailuser. As said in comments, more than likely, there is a typo in the given function.